# How can I use the usb 3.0 port on my case?

Tags: motherboard, usb-3

I recently made a custom built pc. I got an external hard drive that used usb 3.0. My motherboard USB ports are usb 2.0 but my case (nzxt h510 black) has a usb 3.0 on top. There is a big wire coming down from that usb that looks like this: [usb 3.0 wire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm7RK.jpg), but I don’t see anywhere to connect that to my motherboard. My motherboard is the Intel® Desktop Board DQ57TM micro atx.

Comment: You have used a [discontinued 11 year old motherboard](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42486/intel-desktop-board-dq57tm.html). It does not support USB3 at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to [Intel's product listing](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42486/intel-desktop-board-dq57tm.html), your motherboard doesn't come with a USB 3.0 controller so there's indeed nowhere to connect the cable to. (Note how it doesn't have any *external* USB 3.0 ports – that's a good hint that it won't have any internal ones, either.)

You have two options for the cable:

- You could buy a PCI-Express card that comes with its own USB 3 controller. Search online stores for "USB 3 PCIe card". Note that most such cards only have their own USB 3 ports in the back, but there *should* be a few which have a header for connecting the front-panel cable as well.
- You could buy a cheap adapter that allows those ports to be connected to your motherboards USB 2.0 header. Search online stores for "USB 3 to USB 2 pin header adapter". Of course, the ports will work at USB 2.0 speeds only.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I’ll just try the usb 3.0 usb slot.

Answer (score 3):

If your motherboard doesn't have USB 3 then you cannot do anything with that connector.

You might be able to fit and use a [PCI-E to USB 3.0 Expansion Card](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08PF8XR73) of some kind but there is no way to convert USB2 ports to USB3.

Comment: Could I add this to a spare pcie slot https://www.newegg.com/syba-model-sd-mpe20142-mini-pci-express-to-usb-card/p/N82E16815124123?Item=N82E16815124123&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Add-On%20Cards-_-N82E16815124123&gclid=CPalk-6bicwCFY17fgoduMAN5g&gclsrc=aw.ds And then plug the wire into here?

Comment: No. Your motherboard does not appear to have an MiniPCIe slot either according to that page and the dataset I could find. If you can find one I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: How about one like this? [usb 3.0 pcie card](https://www.amazon.com/FebSmart-Self-Powered-Technology-No-Additional-FS-U4-Pro/dp/B072LS4JH7/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=Usb+3+pcie+card&qid=1637322863&s=electronics&sr=1-4)

Comment: There probably are PCIe-miniPCIe adapters available (just like there are PCIe-M.2 ones), although at that point it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: @ihbhuibhuibhuisonicy that second one is a standard PCIe card similar to the one I linked. It should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.